# How to make 2 button side by side in Android

Tags: android, android-studio

I am working on Android project and needed to make 2 button side by side

Answer (score 0):

You Mean like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
      android:id="@+id/button3"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
      android:text="Button"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline13"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
      android:id="@+id/button2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
      android:text="Button"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline13"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
      android:id="@+id/guideline13"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay this is simple you need to choose your xml file and left down the page click on designer then you can move the two button the way you want on the preview screen

Answer (score 0):

You can use this within Linear or Relative layout

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Item Name"

        />
    <Button
        android:text="Item Name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```